# Cant save simple object to CSV after calling ConvertTo-Csv

Tags: powershell, csv, object

I converted an object to the correct format using `CopnverTo-Csv`. If you ask me, it should be very straightforward to then save that content to a CSV file, otherwise **what is the point of ConvertTo-Csv**???

I managed to get the object into the required format with this line

```
$checkListCsv = $checkListObject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object @{name='Name';expression={$_.name}},@{name='Value';expression={$object.($_.name)}} | ConvertTo-Csv
```

When I enter `$checkListCsv` in the console, I see

```
#TYPE Selected.Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition
"Name","Value"
"1 week follow up completed",
"Add to print server",
"Add username to Computer description in AD",
"Additional approved software installation",
"BitLocker enrolment as Admin and user",
"Description",
"Email signature",
"Existing approved none-standard software",
"Hibernation off",
"Install Itunes",
"Install Java",
"Label machine",
"Log into SmartNet",
"Map network drives",
"Map network printers",
"New Machine Name",
"New Machine Serial",
"New Starter",
"Old Machine Name",
"Print card number",
"Sign into OneDrive",
"Skype contact",
"Sound",
"Starting Date",
"Technician",
"Time zone",
"Update required hardware drivers",
"Update ServiceNow",
"User",
"User Data and existing mailboxes",
"VPN client",
"Wireless",
"WP OU",
```

Perfect!

Now all I want to do is save this to a csv file, but for some reason I can't work it out.

I tried

```
$checkListCsv | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\CheckList.csv"
```

But the csv file now contains

```
#TYPE System.String
Length
61
14
29
22
45
44
40
14
18
43
18
17
15
16
20
21
23
19
21
14
19
20
21
16
8
16
13
12
35
20
7
35
13
11
8
```

And I tried `.ToString()` but this just outputs

```
System.Object[]
```

How annoying. What is the correct way to just save the content?

Comment: Do you mean `$checkListCsv | ConvertFrom-Csv`? (My other question is why you want to store it as CSV in the first place? PowerShell works with PSObjects just fine.)

Comment: You're double-converting. You're first converting your objects to CSV strings with `ConvertTo-Csv`; then you're converting those strings to *CSV representations of those string objects* with `Export-Csv`. The fix is to remove the extra conversion.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The script populates the `$checkListObject` properties before exporting to csv. The csv needs to be saved for use in other areas of the business which don't involve PowerShell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either export directly to csv:

```
$checkListObject |
    Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
    Select-Object @{name='Name';expression={$_.name}},@{name='Value';expression={$object.($_.name)}}
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\CheckList.csv"
```

Or, if you use the `$checkListCsv` elsewhere, remove the `ConvertTo-Csv` altogether:

```
$checkListCsv = $checkListObject |
    Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
    Select-Object @{name='Name';expression={$_.name}},@{name='Value';expression={$object.($_.name)}}

    $checkListCsv |Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\CheckList.csv"
```

Or use `Out-File` (not really recommended, just for completeness)

```
$checkListCsv = $checkListObject |
    Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
    Select-Object @{name='Name';expression={$_.name}},@{name='Value';expression={$object.($_.name)}} |
    ConvertTo-Csv

    $checkListCsv | Out-File -Path "C:\temp\CheckList.csv"
```

**Further Explanation**

The [`ConvertTo-Csv` Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-6) takes an object, and gives you back a string (or an array of strings if you have multiple lines). A string has a single property - `Length`

The [`Export-Csv` Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) takes an object, and exports the properties of that object. So pass it an object directly. If you first use `ConvertTo-Csv` you essentially pass it the string array, and it prints out the length of each line...

`Out-File` likes strings and will print you what you get in the console, but it's long winded and pointless if your end goal is a CSV file.